# Error querying entites by date

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa

I'm trying to execute a query, which selects all entities older than 1 day:

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
    // other stuff
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date myDate;
    // getters, setters, etc.pp.
}


// in my DAO class:
Date yesterday = new Date(new Date().getTime()-24*60*60*1000);
TypedQuery<Foo> query = mgr.createQuery("SELECT f FROM Foo f WHERE f.myDate < :dateParam", Foo.class);
query.setParameter("dateParam", yesterday); // also tried adding additional TemporalType.TIMESTAMP parameter ...
```

When this thing is beeing executed it states that `"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type (\"org.datanucleus.query.evaluator.InMemoryQueryResult\") is not that of an entity but needs to be for this operation"`
Is my query faulty? Or the way i handle the dates?

as per request: persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence>

    <persistence-unit name="transactions-optional">
        <provider>org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: I may very well be totally off here, but shouldn't the `TypedQuery` type be `TypedQuery<Foo>`?

Comment: I just broke my real class down to a sample and obviously forgot the change one thing. sorry, edited

Comment: Guessed it was a typo... :) What does your `persistence.xml` look like? Does it perchance have `<exclude-unlisted-classes/>` and no `Foo` listed?

Comment: No, i don't unlist classes, see edit